# PostgreSQL : How to select values with only two digits after decimal point in a table?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have table called `nums`.

```
CREATE TABLE nums (num numeric);
INSERT INTO  nums SELECT * FROM (VALUES(10.11),(11.122),(12.22),(13.555)) t;
```

It have following rows

```
select * from nums

num
--------
10.11
11.122
12.22
13.555
```

So my question is *how to get the values with only two digits after decimal point(`.`)?*

---

Expected Output :-

```
    num
    --------
    10.11
    12.22
```

Comment: `[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]` should do it

Comment: you must need to use word boundaries or anchors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Pattern Matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html)

```
SELECT * FROM nums WHERE num::text ~ '(^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$)';
```

or [Mathematical Functions and Operators - Floor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-math.html)

```
SELECT * FROM nums WHERE FLOOR (num*100)=num*100
```

Comment: @Dan Allen gave the answer with mathematical functions. Why did added the same answer after that? I wouldn't recommend using regex in this case

Comment: @vuwe: Why is this answer accepted? Both queries are *incorrect* and would return `0` or `111.1`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f89c/3

Answer (score 1):

Simply with [`left()` and `right()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT * FROM nums WHERE left(right(num::text, 3), 1) = '.';
```

Or with [`split_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT * FROM nums WHERE length(split_part(num::text, '.', 2)) = 2;
```

Or take the number [`modulo 1`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html) and cast to `text`:

```
SELECT * FROM nums WHERE length((num%1)::text) = 4
```

The last one is independent of the character used for comma.

Aside: you can simplify your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO nums VALUES(10.11),(11.122),(12.22),(13.555);
```

**[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/feae9/1)**

#### Performance

I ran a quick test with a temp table of 100k numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM nums WHERE  ...

left(right(num::text, 3), 1) = '.';        -- Total runtime: 136 ms
length(split_part(num::text, '.', 2)) = 2; -- Total runtime: 162 ms
length((num%1)::text) = 4;                 -- Total runtime: 179 ms
num::text ~ '(^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$)';         -- Total runtime: 280 ms (incorrect!)
FLOOR (num*100)=num*100;                   -- Total runtime: 203 ms (incorrect!)
```

The last two (provided by @varchar) are actually incorrect. See comments and fiddle.